# In the proof of characterization of ampleness of $\mathcal{O}_X$-module

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm reading the Gortz, Algebraic Geometry and now trying to understand some statement.

First, let me arrange some related definitions.

1. Let $X$ be a quasi-compact and quasi-separated scheme. An invertible $\mathcal{O}_X$-module $\mathcal{L}$ is ample if for every quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-module $\mathcal{F}$ of finite type there exists an integer $n_0$ such that $\mathcal{F}\otimes \mathcal{L}^n$ is generated by its global sections for all $n\ge n_0$.
2. Let $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ be a locally ringed space and $\mathcal{F}$ be an $\mathcal{O}_X$-module. Then for $x\in X$, define

$$\mathcal{F}(x) := \mathcal{F}_x/\mathfrak{m}_x\mathcal{F}_x=\mathcal{F}_x \otimes _{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}}\mathcal{\kappa}(x)$$

, called the fiber of $\mathcal{F}$ in $x$. If $f$ is a section of $\mathcal{F}$ over an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$, we denote by **$f(x)$** the image of the germ $f_x \in \mathcal{F}_x$ in $\mathcal{F}(x)$. (his book p.170)

3. Let $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ be a locally ringed space and let $\mathcal{L}$ be an invertible $\mathcal{O}_X$-module. Let $f \in \Gamma(X, \mathcal{L})$  be a global section. Then define

$$ X_f(\mathcal{L}) := \{x \in X : f(x) \neq 0 \in \mathcal{L}(x) \}$$
(his book p.186)

4. And in his book, Remark 13.46. , He states that

[image]

Now, my question is related to next proof of theorem ( his book proposition 13.47) :

[image]

I'm trying to understand the underlined statement. Why the statements are true?

Q. 1. Why $f(x) \neq 0$ in $\mathcal{L}^n$ ?

My first attempt is, since $\mathcal{L}_x$ is flat $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$-module, $(\mathcal{L}^n)_x \cong (\mathcal{L}_x)^n$ is also flat module. So from $\mathcal{I}_x \subseteq \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$, we have an injection $\mathcal{I}_x \otimes _{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}} (\mathcal{L}^n)_x \to (\mathcal{L}^n)_x$ By the assumption (ii) in the proposition 13.47, $\mathcal{I} \otimes \mathcal{L}^n$ is generated by its global sections, say ${f_1, f_2 ,\cdots f_r} \in \Gamma(X, \mathcal{I}\otimes \mathcal{L}^n)$ (can have finitely many? Maybe, since $X$ is quasi-compact and $\mathcal{I} \otimes \mathcal{L}^n$ is of finite type?). And so, one of the $\{f_{1}(x),\cdots f_{r}(x) \}$ is not zero, since they generate $\mathcal{I}_x \otimes _{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}} (\mathcal{L}^n)_x / \mathfrak{m}_x (\mathcal{I}_x \otimes _{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}} (\mathcal{L}^n)_x)= (\mathcal{I} \otimes \mathcal{L}^n)(x)$ (true?). Let $f_{1}(x)$ be nonzero element.

If tensoring by $\kappa(x)$ to the injection $\mathcal{I}_x \otimes _{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}} (\mathcal{L}^n)_x \to (\mathcal{L}^n)_x$ is still injective, $f_1(x) \in (\mathcal{I} \otimes \mathcal{L}^n)(x)$ goes to nonzero element in $\mathcal{L}^n(x)$.

But I stuck at showing the preservation of injectivity under tensoring with the residue field $\kappa(x)$. Is this argument works? Or is there any other method?

Q.2. Why $X_f \subseteq U$?

My first attempt is, since $\mathcal{I}$ is a quasi-coherent ideal of $\mathcal{O}_X$ that defines $Z:=X-U$, $Z = \operatorname{Supp}(\mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{I})$ (His book, Corollary 7.33).
And by the above image, Remark 13.46, $X_f = X - \operatorname{Supp Coker}(u)$ , where $u: \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{L}$ is the corresponding homomorphism of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules from $f$. So, to show that $X_f \subseteq U$, it suffices to show that

$$(\operatorname{Supp Coker}(u))^c \subseteq (\operatorname{Supp}(\mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{I}))^c$$

So, let $x \in \operatorname{Supp Coker}(u))^c$. It means that $\operatorname{Coker}(u_x) = (\operatorname{Coker}(u))_x =0$ ; i.e., $u_x$ is surjective. To show that $x\in (\operatorname{Supp}(\mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{I}))^c$, it suffices to show that $\mathcal{O}_{X,x} = \mathcal{I}_x$. And this is point that I stuck. How can we prove this? I don't know how relate data about $u : \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{L}$ to data about $\mathcal{I}$. It seems that we can use that the $U$ is an affine open and the existence of global generators of $\mathcal{I} \otimes \mathcal{L}^n$. And how?

Or is there any other route?

Anyone helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. is because $\mathcal{I}_U=\mathcal{O}_U$ by definition of $\mathscr{I}$. Indeed, we know that $\mathcal{I} \otimes \mathcal{L}^{\otimes n}$ (for large $n$) is generated by its global sections, so there is a global section $f$ such that $f_x \notin m_{X,x} (\mathcal{I} \otimes \mathcal{L}^{\otimes n})_x$. Since $\mathcal{I}_x=\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$, the image of $f$ (let’s call it $g$) in $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{L}^{\otimes n})$ is such that $g_x \notin m_{X,x}(\mathcal{L}^{\otimes n})_x$ ie $g(x) \neq 0$.
2. It’s enough to show that if $y \notin U$, then $f(y)=0$. Well, if $y \notin U$, then $\mathcal{I}_y \subset m_{X,y}$, so the image of $f_y \in (\mathcal{I} \otimes \mathcal{L}^{\otimes n})_y $ in $(\mathcal{L}^{\otimes n})_y$ actually lands in $m_{X,y}(\mathcal{L}^{\otimes n})_y$ and thus $f_{\mathcal{L}^{\otimes n}}(y)=0$.

Comment: O.K. Can I ask furthur question? First, for 1. , let $\eta : \mathcal{I} \otimes \mathcal{L}^n \to \mathcal{L}^n$ be the canonical morphism (well-defined?) and consider $\eta_x : (\mathcal{I} \otimes \mathcal{L}^n)_x \to \mathcal{L}^n_x$. Then by some commutative diagram, $g_x = \eta_x(f_x)$. Then how can we deduce that $\eta_x(f_x) \notin m_{X,x}(\mathcal{L}^n)_x$ by using $\mathcal{I}_x = \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$? (Since $\mathcal{I}_x = \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$, ($\mathcal{I} \otimes \mathcal{L}^n)_x = \mathcal{L}^n_x$)

Comment: Second, for 2. , similarly, how can we show that $\eta_{y} (f_y) \in m_{X,y}(\mathcal{L}^n_y)$ by using $\mathcal{I}_y \subseteq m_{X,y}$ ?

Comment: Perhaps, you could prove the both statements by direct method? using properties of $\eta_x, \eta_y$? Or, Is there any simple method?

Comment: Uhm.. perhaps, for the second question, is it true since $\eta_y(f_y) \in \mathcal{I}_y(\mathcal{L}^n)_y$.? (I guess that it is true since $I \otimes_A M \cong IM$ for all ideal $I$ of a ring $A$ and $A$-module $M$). Is this correct argument?

Comment: First comment: since $\mathcal{I}_x =\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$, $\eta_x$ is an isomorphic. And $f$ is **chosen so that** $f_x \notin \mathfrak{m}_{X,x}(\mathcal{I} \otimes \mathcal{L}^{\otimes n})_x$, this property carries over through $\eta_x$.

Comment: Second comment: because $\eta_y$ factors (tautologically) through $\mathcal{I}_y\mathcal{L}^n_y \subset \mathfrak{m}_{X,y}\mathcal{L}^{\otimes n}_y$.

Comment: O,K. I think that I somewhat understand. Thank you~~

Comment: Last one of the first comment batch: we *don’t* have $I \otimes_A M  \cong IM$ for any ideal $I$ of a ring $A$ and any $A$-module $M$! It’s only when $M$ is flat.

Comment: Yes. Really it is. Thank you. ~