# $\operatorname{Supp}(\mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{I}) \subseteq \operatorname{Supp Coker}(u_f)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a quasi-compact, quasi-separated scheme and let $\mathcal{L}$ be an invertible $\mathcal{O}_X$-module.
Let $\mathcal{I} $ be a quasi-coherent ideal of $\mathcal{O}_X$ of finite type (finitely generated).

Assume that for some $n>0$, there are global sections $f_1, f_2 ,\cdots f_r \in \Gamma(X, \mathcal{I \otimes L}^n) \subseteq \Gamma({X, \mathcal{L}^n})$ that generates $\mathcal{I \otimes L}^n$ ; i.e., for each $x\in X$, $f_{1,x} , \cdots f_{r,x}$ generates $\mathcal{I}_x\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}} (\mathcal{L}^n)_x$ as $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$-module.

Let $f:=f_1$.

Now consider a homomorphism $u_f : \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{L}^n$,
$$ u_{f,U} : \mathcal{O}_X(U) \to \mathcal{L}^n(U)$$

$$ s \mapsto s \cdot f|_{U}$$

Then, $\operatorname{Supp}(\mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{I}) \subseteq \operatorname{Supp Coker}(u_f)$ ?

; i.e., for $x\in X$, $\mathcal{O}_{X,x} \neq \mathcal{I}_{x}$, which is equivalent to $1_x \notin \mathcal{I}_x$, implies $u_{f,x} : \mathcal{O}_{X,x} \to (\mathcal{L}^n)_x$ is not surjective?

In other words, if $u_{f,x}$ is surjective, then it is necessary that  $1_x \in \mathcal{I}_x$?

This question originates from [In the proof of characterization of ampleness of $\mathcal{O}_X$-module](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4456052/in-the-proof-of-characterization-of-ampleness-of-mathcalo-x-module) which is still not answered. In the post, if our question is true, then we can prove that $X_f \subset U$.

Can anyone helps?

Comment: $u_{f,x}$ is the map $O_{X,x} \rightarrow (L^n)_x$ given by multiplication by $f_x$. It factors through $O_{X,x} \rightarrow (I \otimes L^n)_x=I_{X,x} \otimes_{O_{X,x}} (L^n)_x$ (where it is just multiplication by $f_x$), followed by the multiplication $I_{X,x} \otimes (L^n)_x \rightarrow (L^n)_x$. If that multiplication is surjective (for instance, if $u_{f,x}$ is surjective), then $(L^n)_x=I_{X,x}(L^n)_{x}$ where $(L^n)_x$ is a free $O_{X,x}$-module of rank one. By Nakayama it follows that $I_{X,x}=O_{X,x}$ ie $x$ is not in the support of $O_X/I$.

Comment: Let me follow your comment. First, $\mathcal{I}_{X,x}\otimes \mathcal{L}^n_x \to \mathcal{L}^n_x$ is injective since $\mathcal{L}^n_x$ is flat module. Second, if $u_{f,x}$ is surjecive, then $\mathcal{I}_{X,x}\otimes \mathcal{L}^n_x \to \mathcal{L}^n_x$ is also surjective ; i.e., $\mathcal{I}_{X,x}\otimes \mathcal{L}^n_x \to \mathcal{L}^n_x$ becomes isomorphism. So we have $\mathcal{L}^n_{x}\cong \mathcal{I}_{X,x} \otimes \mathcal{L}^n_x \cong \mathcal{I}_{X,x}(\mathcal{L}^n_x)$. So by the Nakayama lemma, $\mathcal{L}^n_x =0$ (true?)

Comment: And from this, how can we deduce that $\mathcal{O}_{X,x} = \mathcal{I}_{X,x}$?

Comment: You can apply Nakayama in the end only if $\mathcal{I}_{X,x}$ is contained in the maximal ideal! But since the conclusion of the lemma doesn’t hold (obviously $(\mathcal{L}^n)_x$ is nonzero), it means that $\mathcal{I}_{X,x} \not\subset \mathfrak{m}_{X,x}$ so that $\mathcal{I}_{X,x}=\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$.

Comment: Aha! I didn't see carefully the Nakayama Lemma. I see. Thank you!!~